# Why $p(x) = x^4 − 3x^3 + 5x^2 − 3x$ can't be a chromatic polynomial of some graph?

Tags: coloring

> Question: Why $p(x) = x^4 − 3x^3 + 5x^2 − 3x$ can't be a chromatic polynomial of some graph?

We could find that $p(2) = 6>0$, thus $G$ is 2-colorable. I wonder does that imply $G$ is a tree (as it must be triangle-free)? If so, the chromatic polynomial of a tree with 5 vertices is $x(x − 1)^4 \neq p(x).$ Is my reasoning correct? Thanks:)

Comment: Hello :) That your graph is 2-colorable only implies, that it is bipartite, i.e. there are two set $V_1,V_2$, such that $V=V_1\cup V_2$ and $V_1\cap V_2\neq \emptyset$, that there are no edges between two vertices from $V_1$ and no edges between two vertices from $V_2$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks for the comment! How can I prove it can't be the chromatic polynomial? Do I need to check each graph?

Answer (score 2):

Such a graph would have $4$ nodes (because of leading term $x^4$) and $3$ edges (because of $-3x^3$).  There are only a few possibilities to try, and your observation about $2$-colorability rules out one of them.